# Check if all items of a list are string of integers

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, types

I have a dataframe with questions and answers:

```
,Unnamed: 0,Unnamed: 0.1,Unnamed: 0.1.1,URL,QID,Questions,Answers,QType
0,0,0,1,When do you think your next vacation can start?,"['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In next 1 year', 'Only once COVID-19 is under control', 'Only once COVID-19 vaccine is developed']",
1,1,1,2,What are your preferences regarding medical treatment policy (with additional cost)?,"[""Doctor's availability in hotel"", 'Ventilator availability in hotel', 'Tie-ups with nearby hospitals', 'Availability of medical rooms with primary first aid care']",
2,2,2,3,Preferences of complementary breakfast?,"['Buffet breakfast with social distancing', 'Buffet breakfast replaced with Ala-carte with limited options', 'Breakfast to be delivered in room with limited options (chargeable)', 'Packaged breakfast only']",
3,3,3,4,What is your preference for packaged food?,"['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']",
4,4,4,5,Consumer Personality,[],
```

I'd like to get the types of answers in the 'QType' column. That is to say: "taste scale" or "multiple choice". Taste scale are lists of string of integers, multiple choice are all the others:

```
,Unnamed: 0,Unnamed: 0.1,Unnamed: 0.1.1,URL,QID,Questions,Answers,QType
0,0,0,1,When do you think your next vacation can start?,"['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In next 1 year', 'Only once COVID-19 is under control', 'Only once COVID-19 vaccine is developed']",Multiple Choice
1,1,1,2,What are your preferences regarding medical treatment policy (with additional cost)?,"[""Doctor's availability in hotel"", 'Ventilator availability in hotel', 'Tie-ups with nearby hospitals', 'Availability of medical rooms with primary first aid care']",Multiple Choice
2,2,2,3,Preferences of complementary breakfast?,"['Buffet breakfast with social distancing', 'Buffet breakfast replaced with Ala-carte with limited options', 'Breakfast to be delivered in room with limited options (chargeable)', 'Packaged breakfast only']",Multiple Choice
3,3,3,4,What is your preference for packaged food?,"['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']",scale
```

For the moment, I tried the following:

```
>>>def classifier(l):
...     try: 
...         l = ast.literal_eval(l)
...         if all(type(int(item))==int for item in l):
...             l = list(map(int, l))
...     except ValueError:
...         return None
...     j = 0
...     if not l:
...         return None
...     try: 
...         if all(isinstance(x, int) for x in l):
...             print("Likert Scale")
...             return "Likert Scale"
...         else:
...             print("Mult")
...             return "Multiple Choice"
...     except:
...         print("Exception")
...         return None
... df.QType = df.apply(lambda x: classifier(df.Questions), axis = 1)
```

That is to say that every time there are only numbers I say that the question is a scale of numbers, otherwise, it's a multiple-choice.

But it returns `None` because of a ValueError for every bit.

```
df.QType
0       None
1       None
2       None
3       None
4       None
        ... 
2953    None
2954    None
2955    None
2956    None
2957    None
```

Answer (score 0):

### Google Forms API

If you work with Google you can use Google Forms API for this instead of BeautifulSoup: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/

`This service allows scripts to create, access, and modify Google Forms.`

### Google Sheets API

You can also export all responses in a spreadsheet and work with it with Python API. I recommend you this way, because there are more resources about this topic.

Here you find how to export responses:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/139706?hl=en&ref_topic=6063592

and here you find Google Sheets Python API:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

and

https://github.com/burnash/gspread

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I don't own this google form